# What does "dynamodb:*Reserved*" do?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-policies

This permission is under a deny block. I'm trying to figure out what exactly the *reserved* is doing here.

Answer (score 2):

It refers to Amazon DynamoDB reserved capacity. With it you pay a one-time, upfront fee and commit to paying for a minimum usage level at significant savings over a period of time.

So basically the policy deny IAM actions corresponding to dynamodb that includes 'Reserved' in its name. These actions are:

- dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacity. Returns the reserved capacity purchases that are currently in effect.
- dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacityOfferings. Returns details about the reserved capacity plans that are currently offered by AWS.
- dynamodb:PurchaseReservedCapacityOfferings. Performs an actual purchase of reserved capacity.

---

Reference:

[DynamoDB Reserved Capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/iam-policy-prevent-purchase-reserved-capacity.html)

Answer (score 1):

[List of DynamoDB IAM actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazondynamodb.html)

The following actions will be covered under `dynamodb:*Reserved*`

| Action | Description | Access Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DescribeReservedCapacity | Grants permission to describe one or more of the Reserved Capacity purchased | Read |
| DescribeReservedCapacity | Grants permission to describe one or more of the Reserved Capacity purchased | Read |
| PurchaseReservedCapacityOfferings | Grants permission to purchases reserved capacity for use with your account | Write |

`*` is a wildcard character in IAM policy actions [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_action.html)